# how to rename json file using python

Tags: python, json

I would like to save new created json file as a new one with an updated name, for example, the original file name is

```
update.json
```

what I want is

```
{newid_}+update.json
#example:123_update.json
```

```
with open("./update.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

data["Id"] = "newid"

with open("./update.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want to change some ID value inside a file and save it as a file file with that ID as a prefix?

Comment: @mx0 yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value of the new ID in the file name using format string.

```
newId = 'Your ID here'
with open(f"./{newId}_update.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the work:

```
data["Id"] = "newid"
newname = "./"+data["Id"]+"_update.json"

with open(newname, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are saving the new file under `update.json.json`.
In the `open` function, is where you can choose where to write your new file.
So in your case, it could be something like

```py
# Use a f-string to insert the new id into the file name
new_file_path = f"./{data['Id']}_update.json"
with open(new_file_path, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Note that this will not delete the previous file. If you wish to overwrite the previous file, then you can do something like:

```py
import os
file_path = "update.json"
new_file_path = f"./{data['Id']}_update.json"

# Overwrite the content of the old file
with open(file_path, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)

# Rename it
os.rename(file_path, new_file_path)
```

Comment: thank you so much, it gives me a different way to solve the problem